# Can't get Data while fetching from React Error(304)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongoose

While i'm using axios to fetch data it's return 304 on React . But it's work on Postman !

```
 const [mangas, setMangas] = useState([])
        
          useEffect(() => {
            const getMangas = async () => {
              const res = await axios.get('/mangas')
              setMangas(res.data)
            }
            getMangas()
          }, [])
          console.log(mangas)
```

> ::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [16/Aug/2021:10:34:12 +0000] "GET /api/mangas
> HTTP/1.1" 304 -

Morgan return this message on React!

```
  router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
          try {
            const mangas = await Manga.find()
            res.status(200).json(mangas.reverse())
          } catch (err) {
            res.status(500).json(err)
          }
        })
```

> ::1 - - [16/Aug/2021:10:34:44 +0000] "GET /api/mangas HTTP/1.1" 200
> 5763

this is from Postman!

i tried to clear Browser'Cache but it doen't work

Answer (score 1):

304 is not an error. it means the result of the request is the same as the last request the client did.
react knows how to handle this.
You should consider it as "all good. data fetched from cache client side".

what is your problem ?

Comment: Right now i just need to fetch data from the database but i don't know how to get it,, whenever i try to fetch it keeps appear the message . I wonder are there any solution to get data from cache client

Comment: can you try console.log(res.data) juste after initialisation ? it contains data ?

Comment: Thanks for helping bro ! i solve the problem :)

Comment: can you mark my answer as solved then. hf coding

Comment: I did but the website says i have to have at least 15 reputations to do that